# Docker won't copy files from the container to the host's /tmp folder

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu

I am trying to copy a file from a linux container to a linux host using `docker cp`. I want to copy this file to  the `/tmp` folder on the host machine.

The problem is simple: I can copy to other places, such as my home folder. For example, this works:
`docker cp my_container:/certificate.cer /home/adam/Documents/certificate.cer`

But this does not work:
`docker cp my_container:/certificate.cer /tmp/certificate.cer`.

However, the command completes with a zero exit code as if the operation was successful. I get no error feedback, but the file definitely isn't there.

Am I missing something, or is this a bug with the Docker CLI?

edit: From further testing I have noticed that creating a new directory in `/tmp`, (i.e.
`mkdir /tmp/test`) Then trying to copy the file into that subfolder, fails with an error: `stat /tmp/test/: not a directory`.
This seems to indicate that perhaps `docker` is looking at a different folder? I am not sure where it could be looking though.

Thanks

Comment: It could be a file permissions issue. Have you tried running the command as root?

Comment: Unfortunately, I get exactly the same results using `sudo`. I have just noticed something else that might shed some light on the situation, I'll update the question.

Comment: I've tried it on my own machine by creating my own `certificate.cer` in a running container and copying that over to `/tmp/certificate.cer` with `docker cp` and it seems to be working, so not sure what's going wrong here. You could check if other files/directories work for you to see if it's specifically the `certificate.cer`. Maybe you could also create your own file with `docker exec` and see if you can copy that file over (that's how I tested it on my machine), not sure how that would make a difference though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have found the answer to this:

Docker was installed as an Ubuntu Snap, which as I understand, is sandboxed. Running `sudo ls /tmp/snap.docker/tmp` showed me all the files I was missing.

So, it seems the snap version of docker works a little differently than expected. Uninstalling it and reinstalling from `apt` fixed the problem. :)